# plotting multiple waveform graphs in R

Tags: r, loops, plot

I am trying to create a loop in R to plot over 600 spectrograms. I am starting by plotting waveforms first and I cannot figure out what the syntax error is no matter what I try. Perhaps I am not writing the code correctly for this many files but I am not sure. I would appreciate any help.  The code and error is below

```
> library(seewave)
> setwd("~/Herp Team/ACLF 2020/ACLF/ACLF_Audiomoth_13")
> library(tuneR)
> library(signal)
>audiomoth13<-"~/Herp Team/ACLF 2020/ACLF/ACLF_Audiomoth_13"
>audiomoth13wavfiles <- Sys.glob("*.WAV")
for (audiomoth13wavfiles in audiomoth13) {
audiomoth13_allfiles<- readWave("5E5D6728.WAV","5E5D75B0.WAV","5E5D8438.WAV","5E5D92C0.WAV","5E5D9E00.WAV","5E5DAC88.WAV","5E5DBB10.WAV","5E5DC998.WAV","5E5E8D10.WAV","5E5E9B98.WAV","5E5EAA20.WAV","5E5EB8A8.WAV","5E5EC730.WAV","5E5ED5B8.WAV","5E5EE440.WAV","5E5EEF80.WAV","5E5EFE08.WAV","5E5F0C90.WAV","5E5F1B18.WAV","5E5FDE90.WAV","5E5FED18.WAV","5E5FFBA0.WAV","5E600A28.WAV","5E6018B0.WAV","5E602738.WAV","5E6035C0.WAV","5E604100.WAV","5E604F88.WAV","5E605E10.WAV","5E606C98.WAV","5E613010.WAV","5E613E98.WAV","5E614D20.WAV","5E615BA8.WAV","5E616A30.WAV","5E6178B8.WAV","5E618740.WAV","5E619280.WAV","5E61A108.WAV","5E61AF90.WAV","5E61BE18.WAV","5E628190.WAV","5E629018.WAV","5E629EA0.WAV","5E62AD28.WAV","5E62BBB0.WAV","5E62CA38.WAV","5E62D8C0.WAV","5E62E400.WAV","5E62F288.WAV","5E630110.WAV","5E630F98.WAV","5E63D310.WAV","5E63E198.WAV","5E63F020.WAV","5E63FEA8.WAV","5E640D30.WAV","5E641BB8.WAV","5E642A40.WAV","5E643580.WAV","5E644408.WAV","5E645290.WAV","5E646118.WAV","5E652490.WAV","5E653318.WAV","5E6541A0.WAV","5E655028.WAV","5E655EB0.WAV","5E656D38.WAV","5E657BC0.WAV","5E658700.WAV","5E659588.WAV","5E65A410.WAV","5E65B298.WAV","5E667610.WAV","5E668498.WAV","5E669320.WAV","5E66A1A8.WAV","5E66B030.WAV","5E66BEB8.WAV","5E66CD40.WAV","5E66D880.WAV","5E66E708.WAV","5E66F590.WAV","5E670418.WAV","5E67C790.WAV","5E67D618.WAV","5E67E4A0.WAV","5E67F328.WAV","5E6801B0.WAV","5E681038.WAV","5E681EC0.WAV","5E682A00.WAV","5E683888.WAV","5E684710.WAV","5E685598.WAV","5E691910.WAV","5E692798.WAV","5E693620.WAV","5E6944A8.WAV","5E695330.WAV","5E6961B8.WAV","5E697040.WAV","5E697B80.WAV","5E698A08.WAV","5E699890.WAV","5E69A718.WAV","5E6A6A90.WAV","5E6A7918.WAV","5E6A87A0.WAV","5E6A9628.WAV","5E6AA4B0.WAV","5E6AB338.WAV","5E6AC1C0.WAV","5E6ACD00.WAV","5E6ADB88.WAV","5E6AEA10.WAV","5E6AF898.WAV","5E6BBC10.WAV","5E6BCA98.WAV","5E6BD920.WAV","5E6BE7A8.WAV","5E6BF630.WAV","5E6C04B8.WAV","5E6C1340.WAV","5E6C1E80.WAV","5E6C2D08.WAV","5E6C3B90.WAV","5E6C4A18.WAV","5E6D0D90.WAV","5E6D1C18.WAV","5E6D2AA0.WAV","5E6D3928.WAV","5E6D47B0.WAV","5E6D5638.WAV","5E6D64C0.WAV","5E6D7000.WAV","5E6D7E88.WAV","5E6D8D10.WAV","5E6D9B98.WAV","5E6E5F10.WAV","5E6E6D98.WAV","5E6E7C20.WAV","5E6E8AA8.WAV","5E6E9930.WAV","5E6EA7B8.WAV","5E6EB640.WAV","5E6EC180.WAV","5E6ED008.WAV","5E6EDE90.WAV","5E6EED18.WAV","5E6FB090.WAV","5E6FBF18.WAV","5E6FCDA0.WAV","5E6FDC28.WAV","5E6FEAB0.WAV","5E6FF938.WAV","5E7007C0.WAV","5E701300.WAV","5E702188.WAV","5E703010.WAV","5E703E98.WAV","5E710210.WAV","5E711098.WAV","5E711F20.WAV","5E712DA8.WAV","5E713C30.WAV","5E714AB8.WAV","5E715940.WAV","5E716480.WAV","5E717308.WAV","5E718190.WAV","5E719018.WAV","5E725390.WAV","5E726218.WAV","5E7270A0.WAV","5E73B795.WAV","5E73C220.WAV","5E73D0A8.WAV","5E73DF30.WAV","5E73EDB8.WAV","5E73FC40.WAV","5E740780.WAV","5E741608.WAV","5E742490.WAV","5E743318.WAV","5E74F690.WAV","5E750518.WAV","5E7513A0.WAV","5E752228.WAV","5E7530B0.WAV","5E753F38.WAV","5E754DC0.WAV","5E755900.WAV","5E756788.WAV","5E757610.WAV","5E758498.WAV","5E764810.WAV","5E765698.WAV","5E766520.WAV","5E7673A8.WAV","5E768230.WAV","5E7690B8.WAV","5E769F40.WAV","5E76AA80.WAV","5E76B908.WAV","5E76C790.WAV","5E76D618.WAV","5E779990.WAV","5E77A818.WAV","5E77B6A0.WAV","5E77C528.WAV","5E77D3B0.WAV","5E77E238.WAV","5E77F0C0.WAV","5E77FC00.WAV","5E780A88.WAV","5E781910.WAV","5E782798.WAV","5E78EB10.WAV","5E78F998.WAV","5E790820.WAV","5E7916A8.WAV","5E792530.WAV","5E7933B8.WAV","5E794240.WAV","5E794D80.WAV","5E795C08.WAV","5E796A90.WAV","5E797918.WAV","5E7A3C90.WAV","5E7A4B18.WAV","5E7A59A0.WAV","5E7A6828.WAV","5E7A76B0.WAV","5E7A8538.WAV","5E7A93C0.WAV","5E7A9F00.WAV","5E7AAD88.WAV","5E7ABC10.WAV","5E7ACA98.WAV","5E7B8E10.WAV","5E7B9C98.WAV","5E7BAB20.WAV","5E7BB9A8.WAV","5E7BC830.WAV","5E7BD6B8.WAV","5E7BE540.WAV","5E7BF080.WAV","5E7BFF08.WAV","5E7C0D90.WAV","5E7C1C18.WAV","5E7CDF90.WAV","5E7CEE18.WAV","5E7CFCA0.WAV","5E7D0B28.WAV","5E7D19B0.WAV","5E7D2838.WAV","5E7D36C0.WAV","5E7D4200.WAV","5E7D5088.WAV","5E7D5F10.WAV","5E7D6D98.WAV","5E7E3110.WAV","5E7E3F98.WAV","5E7E4E20.WAV","5E7E5CA8.WAV","5E7E6B30.WAV","5E7E79B8.WAV","5E7E8840.WAV","5E7E9380.WAV","5E7EA208.WAV","5E7EB090.WAV","5E7EBF18.WAV","5E7F8290.WAV","5E7F9118.WAV","5E7F9FA0.WAV","5E7FAE28.WAV","5E7FBCB0.WAV","5E7FCB38.WAV","5E7FD9C0.WAV","5E7FE500.WAV","5E7FF388.WAV","5E800210.WAV","5E801098.WAV","5E80D410.WAV","5E80E298.WAV","5E80F120.WAV","5E80FFA8.WAV","5E810E30.WAV","5E811CB8.WAV","5E812B40.WAV","5E813680.WAV","5E814508.WAV","5E815390.WAV","5E816218.WAV","5E822590.WAV","5E823418.WAV","5E8242A0.WAV","5E825128.WAV","5E825FB0.WAV","5E826E38.WAV","5E827CC0.WAV","5E828800.WAV","5E829688.WAV","5E82A510.WAV","5E82B398.WAV","5E837710.WAV","5E838598.WAV","5E839420.WAV","5E83A2A8.WAV","5E83B130.WAV","5E83BFB8.WAV","5E83CE40.WAV","5E83D980.WAV","5E83E808.WAV","5E83F690.WAV","5E840518.WAV","5E84C890.WAV","5E84D718.WAV","5E84E5A0.WAV","5E84F428.WAV","5E8502B0.WAV","5E851138.WAV","5E851FC0.WAV","5E852B00.WAV","5E853988.WAV","5E854810.WAV","5E855698.WAV","5E861A10.WAV","5E862898.WAV","5E863720.WAV","5E8645A8.WAV","5E865430.WAV","5E8662B8.WAV","5E867140.WAV","5E867C80.WAV","5E868B08.WAV","5E869990.WAV","5E86A818.WAV","5E876B90.WAV","5E877A18.WAV","5E8788A0.WAV","5E879728.WAV","5E87A5B0.WAV","5E87B438.WAV","5E87C2C0.WAV","5E87CE00.WAV","5E87DC88.WAV","5E87EB10.WAV","5E87F998.WAV","5E88BD10.WAV","5E88CB98.WAV","5E88DA20.WAV","5E88E8A8.WAV","5E88F730.WAV","5E8905B8.WAV","5E891440.WAV","5E891F80.WAV","5E892E08.WAV","5E893C90.WAV","5E894B18.WAV","5E8A0E90.WAV","5E8A1D18.WAV","5E8A2BA0.WAV","5E8A3A28.WAV","5E8A48B0.WAV","5E8A5738.WAV","5E8A65C0.WAV","5E8A7100.WAV","5E8A7F88.WAV","5E8A8E10.WAV","5E8A9C98.WAV","5E8B6010.WAV","5E8B6E98.WAV","5E8B7D20.WAV","5E8B8BA8.WAV","5E8B9A30.WAV","5E8BA8B8.WAV","5E8BB740.WAV","5E8BC280.WAV","5E8BD108.WAV","5E8BDF90.WAV","5E8BEE18.WAV","5E8CB190.WAV","5E8CC018.WAV","5E8CCEA0.WAV","5E8CDD28.WAV","5E8CEBB0.WAV","5E8CFA38.WAV","5E8D08C0.WAV","5E8D1400.WAV","5E8D2288.WAV","5E8D3110.WAV","5E8D3F98.WAV","5E8E0310.WAV","5E8E1198.WAV","5E8E2020.WAV","5E8E2EA8.WAV","5E8E3D30.WAV","5E8E4BB8.WAV","5E8E5A40.WAV","5E8E6580.WAV","5E8E7408.WAV","5E8E8290.WAV","5E8E9118.WAV","5E8F5490.WAV","5E8F6318.WAV","5E8F71A0.WAV","5E8F8028.WAV","5E8F8EB0.WAV","5E8F9D38.WAV","5E8FABC0.WAV","5E8FB700.WAV","5E8FC588.WAV","5E8FD410.WAV","5E8FE298.WAV","5E90A610.WAV","5E90B498.WAV","5E90C320.WAV","5E90D1A8.WAV","5E90E030.WAV","5E90EEB8.WAV","5E90FD40.WAV","5E910880.WAV","5E911708.WAV","5E912590.WAV","5E913418.WAV","5E91F790.WAV","5E920618.WAV","5E9214A0.WAV","5E922328.WAV","5E9231B0.WAV","5E924038.WAV","5E924EC0.WAV","5E925A00.WAV","5E926888.WAV","5E927710.WAV","5E928598.WAV","5E934910.WAV","5E935798.WAV","5E936620.WAV","5E9374A8.WAV","5E938330.WAV","5E9391B8.WAV","5E93A040.WAV","5E93AB80.WAV","5E93BA08.WAV","5E93C890.WAV","5E93D718.WAV","5E949A90.WAV","5E94A918.WAV","5E94B7A0.WAV","5E94C628.WAV","5E94D4B0.WAV","5E94E338.WAV","5E94F1C0.WAV","5E94FD00.WAV","5E950B88.WAV","5E951A10.WAV","5E952898.WAV","5E95EC10.WAV","5E95FA98.WAV","5E960920.WAV","5E9617A8.WAV","5E962630.WAV","5E9634B8.WAV","5E964340.WAV","5E964E80.WAV","5E965D08.WAV","5E966B90.WAV","5E967A18.WAV","5E973D90.WAV","5E974C18.WAV","5E975AA0.WAV","5E976928.WAV","5E9777B0.WAV","5E978638.WAV","5E9794C0.WAV","5E97A000.WAV","5E97AE88.WAV","5E97BD10.WAV","5E97CB98.WAV","5E988F10.WAV","5E989D98.WAV","5E98AC20.WAV","5E98BAA8.WAV","5E98C930.WAV","5E98D7B8.WAV","5E98E640.WAV","5E98F180.WAV","5E990008.WAV","5E990E90.WAV","5E991D18.WAV","5E99E090.WAV","5E99EF18.WAV","5E99FDA0.WAV","5E9A0C28.WAV","5E9A1AB0.WAV","5E9A2938.WAV","5E9A37C0.WAV","5E9A4300.WAV","5E9A5188.WAV","5E9A6010.WAV","5E9A6E98.WAV","5E9B3210.WAV","5E9B4098.WAV","5E9B4F20.WAV","5E9B5DA8.WAV","5E9B6C30.WAV","5E9B7AB8.WAV","5E9B8940.WAV","5E9B9480.WAV","5E9BA308.WAV","5E9BB190.WAV","5E9BC018.WAV","5E9C8390.WAV","5E9C9218.WAV","5E9CA0A0.WAV","5E9CAF28.WAV","5E9CBDB0.WAV","5E9CCC38.WAV","5E9CDAC0.WAV","5E9CE600.WAV","5E9CF488.WAV","5E9D0310.WAV","5E9D1198.WAV","5E9DD510.WAV","5E9DE398.WAV","5E9DF220.WAV","5E9E00A8.WAV","5E9E0F30.WAV","5E9E1DB8.WAV","5E9E2C40.WAV","5E9E3780.WAV","5E9E4608.WAV","5E9E5490.WAV","5E9E6318.WAV","5E9F2690.WAV","5E9F3518.WAV","5E9F43A0.WAV","5E9F5228.WAV","5E9F60B0.WAV","5E9F6F38.WAV","5E9F7DC0.WAV","5E9F8900.WAV","5E9F9788.WAV","5E9FA610.WAV","5E9FB498.WAV","5EA07810.WAV","5EA08698.WAV","5EA09520.WAV","5EA0A3A8.WAV","5EA0B230.WAV","5EA0C0B8.WAV","5EA0CF40.WAV","5EA0DA80.WAV","5EA0E908.WAV","5EA0F790.WAV","5EA10618.WAV","5EA1C990.WAV","5EA1D818.WAV","5EA1E6A0.WAV","5EA1F528.WAV","5EA203B0.WAV","5EA21238.WAV","5EA220C0.WAV","5EA22C00.WAV","5EA23A88.WAV","5EA24910.WAV","5EA25798.WAV","5EA31B10.WAV","5EA32998.WAV","5EA33820.WAV","5EA346A8.WAV","5EA35530.WAV","5EA363B8.WAV","5EA37240.WAV","5EA37D80.WAV","5EA38C08.WAV","5EA39A90.WAV","5EA3A918.WAV","5EA46C90.WAV","5EA47B18.WAV","5EA489A0.WAV","5EA49828.WAV","5EA4A6B0.WAV","5EA4B538.WAV","5EA4C3C0.WAV","5EA4CF00.WAV","5EA4DD88.WAV","5EA4EC10.WAV","5EA4FA98.WAV","5EA5BE10.WAV","5EA5CC98.WAV","5EA5DB20.WAV","5EA5E9A8.WAV","5EA5F830.WAV","5EA606B8.WAV","5EA61540.WAV","5EA62080.WAV","5EA62F08.WAV","5EA63D90.WAV","5EA64C18.WAV","5EA70F90.WAV","5EA71E18.WAV","5EA72CA0.WAV","5EA73B28.WAV","5EA749B0.WAV","5EA75838.WAV","5EA766C0.WAV","5EA77200.WAV","5EA78088.WAV","5EA78F10.WAV","5EA79D98.WAV","5EA86110.WAV","5EA86F98.WAV","5EA87E20.WAV","5EA88CA8.WAV","5EA89B30.WAV","5EA8A9B8.WAV","5EA8B840.WAV","5EA8C380.WAV","5EA8D208.WAV","5EA8E090.WAV","5EA8EF18.WAV","5EA9B290.WAV","5EA9C118.WAV","5EA9CFA0.WAV","5EA9DE28.WAV","5EA9ECB0.WAV","5EA9FB38.WAV","5EAA09C0.WAV","5EAA1500.WAV","5EAA2388.WAV","5EAA3210.WAV","5EAA4098.WAV","5EAB0410.WAV","5EAB1298.WAV","5EAB2120.WAV","5EAB2FA8.WAV","5EAB3E30.WAV","5EAB4CB8.WAV","5EAB5B40.WAV","5EAB6680.WAV","5EAB7508.WAV","5EAB8390.WAV","5EAB9218.WAV","5EAC5590.WAV","5EAC6418.WAV","5EAC72A0.WAV","5EAC8128.WAV","5EAC8FB0.WAV","5EAC9E38.WAV","5EACACC0.WAV","5EACB800.WAV","5EACC688.WAV","5EACD510.WAV","5EACE398.WAV","5EADA710.WAV","5EADB598.WAV","5EADC420.WAV","5EADD2A8.WAV","5EADE130.WAV","5EADEFB8.WAV","5EADFE40.WAV","5EAE0980.WAV","5EAE1808.WAV","5EAE2690.WAV","5EAE3518.WAV","5EAEF890.WAV","5EAF0718.WAV","5EAF15A0.WAV","5EAF2428.WAV","5EAF32B0.WAV","5EAF4138.WAV","5EAF4FC0.WAV","5EAF5B00.WAV","5EAF6988.WAV","5EAF7810.WAV","5EAF8698.WAV","5EB04A10.WAV","5EB05898.WAV","5EB06720.WAV","5EB075A8.WAV","5EB08430.WAV","5EB092B8.WAV","5EB0A140.WAV","5EB0AC80.WAV","5EB0BB08.WAV","5EB0C990.WAV","5EB0D818.WAV")
snd<-audiomoth13_allfiles@left 
fs<-audiomoth13_allfiles@samp.rate
dur<-length(snd)/audiomoth13_allfiles@samp.rate
snd<-snd-mean(snd)
timearray<-(0:(5760000-1))/audiomoth13_allfiles@samp.rate
plot(timearray,snd,type='l',xlab='Time',ylab='Amplitude')
file.path("C:","Herp Team","ACLF 2020","ACLF", "ACLF_Audiomoth_13", paste("waveplot_",".jpeg", sep=""))
} 
Error: unexpected symbol in:"plot(timearray,snd,type='l',xlab='Time',ylab='Amplitude')file.path("C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop will loop once and your `readWave` call has multiple arguments when it is expecting one.

To improve this, you can use `list.files` to find the files of interest and then use the return from this to control a for loop. The `tuneR` function is able to plot things. I'm not quite sure what you exactly want to do but I show the use of the `seewave::duration` function to get the duration of a wav file.

Here's a small reproducible example to show all of this.

```
library(seewave)
# make some data to create a reproducible example
dir.create('tmp')
setwd('tmp')
data(orni)
writeWave(orni, 'orni.wav')
data(tico)
writeWave(tico, 'tico.wav')
    
wavfiles <- list.files(pattern = '[.]wav', full.names = T)
for (wavfile in wavfiles) {       # loop through all the files
    wav <- readWave(wavfile)      # read the single wav
    dur <- seewave::duration(wav) # the duration
    tuneR::plot(wav)              # plot 
}
```

[image: plot 1]
[image: plot 2]